# How to move a TrueCrypt's container that contains a virtual machine to another HD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, virtual-machine, vmware, truecrypt

I have a two HDs in my computer. One of them is a SSD of 167 GB approximatelly, the other is a SATA 1 TB. 
The SSD is partitioned in two, partitions C and E, and the 1 TB HD is the partition D. Inside partion E, I have a TrueCrypt container that I always mount as a partition under name P.
Inside partion P I have a virtual Machine, VMWare, with Windows XP installed.
I need more space in partition C, to install more programs, so I was thinking to tranfer everything on the partition E to the HD of 1T( partition D ) and tranfer space from partition E to partition C. This way I will have only two partitions C and D, the P partition will exist when I mount TrueCrypt partition from the container that will be now in the partition D.

So, I was thinking. What can I do to tranfer and have things this way, I'm affraid of my virtual Machine stops working because of this. Does someone has an advice or tip of how to do it safelly ?

**EDITED:**

Based on the first two comments, I think other people can have the same doubt or opinion, so I will explain here. I know TrueCrypt is old and that SSD HD is faster, but I still prefer it that way because in the VM I don't need performance of the HD and the TrueCrypt is the solution that people here, in my lab, use. So I just use TrueCrypt because of this.

Comment: A container is just a file, it can be anywhere. This is a non-issue,  a non-starter.  But Truecrypt is abandoned, obsolete,  there's Veracrypt  now.

Comment: Continuing from the first comment,  although it doesn't matter where the file is,  the performance in your case will be noticeably worse because it'll be running from a much slower HDD.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  , thanks, so, with relation to TrueCrypt it will not be a problem to move the container, is it right ?. So, if I move the container from partition E to partition D, when I mount partition P from container in D using TrueCrypt, it will be no problem for the VMware ? I mean, my Virtual Machine will work fine as if nothing had changed ?

Comment: Again, it's just a file, it doesn't matter where it physically resides,  when opened it'll behave the same  as always (but much slower  than before).

Comment: You should just copy the file and then open the copied file instead. If the performance isn't an issue then go ahead and delete the original. Regarding Truecrypt it was discontinued not long after the release of Windows 8 (a long time ago...).  Veracrypt is what replaced TC for the exact same purpose, works the same  way and with an identical gui but the difference  is it's UPDATED, maintained. Anyone using TC in 2019 is really misinformed or worse.

Comment: Regardless of where the TrueCrypt (or VeraCrypt) file itself is stored, if you *mount* it to the same drive letter, then your virtual machine won't know the difference (other than possible performance differences).